# Subquery return more than 1 value in deletion statement using datediff

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
delete from Rentals
where (select datediff(day, OrderDate, actualReturnDate) 
       from Orders 
       inner join rentals on Orders.orderNumber = Rentals.orderNumber) > 60
```

I'm getting an error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subqueries you have in your queries return more than one value, which is not allowed if you compare them to a single value.

What I suspect is that you are simply writing your delete statement the wrong way. Your question is rather thin on what it is you are trying to achieve.

I'll take a guess at what you intended to write:

```
delete Rentals 
from Orders 
     INNER JOIN rentals ON Orders.orderNumber=Rentals.orderNumber
where DATEDIFF(day, OrderDate, actualReturnDate)>60
```

which would delete rows in `rentals` where the difference between the `orderdate` and `actualreturndate` are bigger than 60 for the orders associated with the rental.

Note that since you have problems writing a rather trivial query like this, it is a good idea to first read a good book or anything that will teach you the fundamentals of writing T-SQL queries.

Comment: Let me suggest that before running this, check to make sure you are going to delete the rows you really want to by replacing the "delete Rentals" line with "Select Rentals.* " which will give you a list of everything you would delete.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
delete from Rentals
where Rentals.ID in (select rentals.ID
       from Orders 
       inner join rentals on Orders.orderNumber = Rentals.orderNumber
       datediff(day, OrderDate, actualReturnDate) > 60)
```

after "WHERE", Sql compare values in a field (in this situation, field = column), not collection of values

Answer (score 0):

That part of the query is not valid:

```
(select datediff(day, OrderDate, actualReturnDate) 
       from Orders 
       inner join rentals on Orders.orderNumber = Rentals.orderNumber) > 60
```

That is because select statement returns more than one row and SQL engine can't identify wich datediff should be compared with 60, i.e. both? only the first? in or, in and?... that is not clear that's why SQL engine is complaining. You can include the filter inside the subquery or rewrite the query as TT. did.